# TinyMCE and TinyBrowser Cross SubDomains

Tags: javascript, tinymce, cross-domain

I have tinyMCE and tinyBrowser (to upload and manage files) running fine on my production server. The files are increasing and I decided to separate tinyBrowser to a different server.

Now what I am trying to do is to have tinyMCE on the main production server: a.domain.com and call the tinybrowser from a different sub domain say b.domain.com/tinybrowser.php

Tinybrowser is working fine independently but the two are unable to communicate with each other. I understand this is a cross domain issue, but I am unable to solve it. Is there any other alternative I can use to primarily solve the pain point of hosting files on a different server when uploaded using tinyMCE/tinyBrowser

Thanks
Sparsh Gupta

Answer (score 2):

You will want to make adjustments in 2 places:

1. in tiny_mce_popup.js:

   - uncomment `//document.domain = 'domain.com';`
     (so it looks like):
     `document.domain = 'domain.com';`
2. In any places where you have initilized tinyMCE (i.e. called `tinyMCE.init({ ..`)
   place:
   `document.domain = 'domain.com';`

above:
`tinyMCE.init({`

so it'll look like:

```
document.domain = 'domain.com';
tinyMCE.init({
...
```